# How to add a Pinterest "Pin it" button in a prettyphoto

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, pinterest, prettyphoto

I have recently used a "pin it" button in my WordPress website.

I have added a Pinterest button just after a "Facebook like" button.

Social_tools:

`encodeURIComponent(location.href.replace(location.hash, "")) + '&media="{path}"&description={title}" class="pin-it-button"` ...

When I click a `Pin it` button, it does not show image and title.

The url shows like this:

http://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.siriinc.com%2F9180-bianca-bridal-dress%2F&media={path}&description={title}

I have not used a JavaScript before. How do I get path and title for this button?

Comment: I signed up for Pinterest just for you, but I don't understand. I clicked the PinIt button on your website and it worked. What isn't working for you? Or is [www.siriinc.com](http://siriinc.com) not your website?

Comment: please check this link http://www.siriinc.com/9181-petula-bridal-dress/ and when you click an image in a left side. lightbox will popup  with social icons. when we click "pinit" icon then it goes to the pinterest but image and content doesnot shows.i have added this link  
http://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.siriinc.com%2F9180-bianca-bridal-dress%2F&media={path}&description={title} in a prettyphoto js file